# Neo4j unable start on Centos

Tags: java, linux, neo4j, centos

I am going to install neo4j-community-2.1.6 on my Centos Server with JAVA version 1.7.0_60. 
I followed [this instruction from neo4j](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-installation.html#linux-install)

When I tried to start it, I got this error :

```
bin/utils: line 38: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token ('
bin/utils: line 38: syntax error near ^([
bin/utils: line 38:       if [[ ${line} =~ ^([^#\s][^=]+)=(.+)$ ]]; then
./neo4j: line 60: getconfigquoted: command not found
./neo4j: line 61: getconfigquoted: command not found
./neo4j: line 154: detectos: command not found
./neo4j: line 155: exitonnojava: command not found
./neo4j: line 156: checkstatus: command not found
./neo4j: line 157: checklimits: command not found
./neo4j: line 159: checkjvmcompatibility: command not found
./neo4j: line 141: [: =: unary operator expected
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
./neo4j: line 169: [: =: unary operator expected
Starting Neo4j Server..../neo4j: line 186: checkclasspath: command not found
./neo4j: line 187: checkandrepairenv: command not found
process [13449]... waiting for server to be ready. Failed to start within 120 seconds
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

I checked the log, I only see this :

```
bash: : command not found
```

Appreciate if someone could give me advice on how to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the bash shell installed, which is really weird for CentOS.

You need to [use yum](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-managing-packages.html) to install bash, which ought to already be there.   Try running:

```
yum install bash
```

As the root user.

Comment: Looks like bash shell is not up to date. I ran yum install bash, and now the problem is solved. Thanks!